# BigQuery Dataflow LoadJob get failed rows and skip error throwing when any record failed

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

How to correct handle saving pubsub messages with LoadJob in Dataform?

```
try:
  job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
   source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
   schema_update_options=[
     bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION,
     bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION
   ],
   write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
 )

  load_job = self.client.load_table_from_json(
                json_text,
                table_id,
                job_config=job_config,
            ) 
  load_job.result() 

except BadRequest as error:
 ...
```

but if i try load

```
[{error_row, correct_row}]
```

correct_row will not be loaded, error row throw exception.

I expecting:

data: [{error_row},{correct_row}]

```
try:
  ...
except:
  only get a failed rows
```

correct_rows shoudl be loaded to the db

Answer (score 0):

If you use streaming inserts, the BigQuery insertAll API does return failing rows (see [response body docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll#response-body)) although I'm not sure what interacting with that looks like from the beam python API.

Your example here, though, is using file loads and it's expected behavior that a `LoadJob` will fail if any record is invalid. If your use case can tolerate dropping invalid rows, then you can take a look at the [max_bad_records](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig#google_cloud_bigquery_job_LoadJobConfig_max_bad_records) configuration option.

If you need to be able to keep failing rows, then either look into using the streaming API or perhaps implement your own validation logic within your pipeline before sending the data to BigQuery.